# Encountering with exception fs.js:747 throw new Error('use fs.watch api instead');

Tags: node.js, mongodb

While runing the following code on Node.js i am facing this exception fs.js:747 throw new Error('use fs.watch api instead');.  **

- node version 0.6.18 npm version is 1.1.21

** The code i am using is

```
**/*
 * Monitor remote server uptime.
 */

var mongoose   = require('mongoose');  
var express    = require('express');
var config     = require('config');
var socketIo   = require('socket.io');
var path       = require('path');
var monitor    = require('./lib/monitor');
var analyzer   = require('./lib/analyzer');
var CheckEvent = require('./models/checkEvent');
var Ping       = require('./models/ping');

// configure mongodb

mongoose.connect('mongodb://' + config.mongodb.user + ':' + config.mongodb.password + '@' + 
    config.mongodb.server +'/' + config.mongodb.database);

mongoose.connection.on('error', function (err) {
  console.error('MongoDB error: ' + err.message);
  console.error('Make sure a mongoDB server is running and accessible by this application')
});

if (config.autoStartMonitor) {
  m = monitor.createMonitor(config.monitor);
  m.start();
}

a = analyzer.createAnalyzer(config.analyzer);
a.start();

var app = module.exports = express.createServer();

// Site

app.configure(function(){
  app.use(app.router);

  // the following middlewares are only necessary for the mounted 'dashboard' app, 
  // but express needs it on the parent app (?) and it therefore pollutes the api

  app.use(express.bodyParser());
  app.use(express.methodOverride());
  app.use(express.cookieParser());
  app.use(express.session({ secret: 'qdfegsgkjhflkquhfskqdjfhskjdfh' }));
});

app.configure('development', function() {
  if (config.verbose) mongoose.set('debug', true);
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));
  app.use(express.errorHandler({ dumpExceptions: true, showStack: true }));
});

app.configure('production', function() {
  var oneYear = 31557600000;
  app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public', { maxAge: oneYear }));
  app.use(express.errorHandler());
});

// Routes

app.use('/api',       require('./app/api/app'));
app.use('/dashboard', require('./app/dashboard/app'));

app.get('/', function(reaq, res) {
  res.redirect('/dashboard/events');
});

// Sockets

var io = socketIo.listen(app);

io.configure('production', function() {
  io.enable('browser client etag');
  io.set('log level', 1);
});

io.configure('development', function() {
  if (!config.verbose) io.set('log level', 1);
});

CheckEvent.on('postInsert', function(event) {
  io.sockets.emit('CheckEvent', event.toJSON());
});

io.sockets.on('connection', function(socket) {
  socket.on('set check', function(check) {
    socket.set('check', check);
  });

  Ping.on('postInsert', function(ping) {
    socket.get('check', function(err, check) {
      if (ping.check == check) {
        socket.emit('ping', ping);
      }
    });
  });
});

// load plugins

path.exists('./plugins/index.js', function(exists) {
  if (exists) {![enter image description here][1]
    require('./plugins').init(app, io, config, mongoose);
  };
});

app.listen(config.server.port);
console.log("Express server listening on port %d in %s mode", config.server.port,     
app.settings.env);
```

Any resolutions??

Comment: Please fix the formatting of your question! See http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. Also consider reducing the code to include only the necessary stuff - see http://sscce.org/

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be running on Windows, and using `fs.watchFile` that is unsupported on Windows.